# Show and Hiding information in ASP.NET data grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

i have a datagrid which contains a lot of information in one column. 
I would like a way for the user to preview some of the content in that column and then click a "more" hyperlink in that column that takes them to another page that displays all the information in that column allowing them to add more info into it and other items in that row.

I have done the more hyper link on the end of all the information but i would i change for example:

"HI my name is stefan i like walking on the beach and other stuff...more"

to

"Hi my name is stefan... more"

And how would i pull up the selected row in an new datagrid on a new asp page after they click more?

[image: what I've got]

[image: visualstudio view]

[image: clicking more hyper link]

When i click the more hyperlink it doesn't open the correct row but only blogid 2.

Comment: What have you tried? I presume you understand that your column would have to contain something other than text? Are you aware of your options for other kinds of columns?

Comment: Hi I've tried converting it to a template following guides on the net but that hasn't helped me. Ive now successfully got the hyperlink for the more button going to another page but it displays the first row on the table not the row i clicked more on?

Comment: The DataGrid is really old, the DataGridView is used with Windows forms.  Do you mean GridView?

Comment: You should show us what you have, and ask for help in making it work. The way you asked your question makes us think you're lazy and haven't done any work, and that you are asking us to do your work for you. Now that you've told us that you tried templates, please post an example of your current "best effort". We'll help.

Comment: hi i wanted to but i didn't have enough points to upload images, I'm sorry, but i do now!

Comment: Thanks for the images; I meant show us some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using an sql query,
Left(content,50)

Which displays the first 50 characters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HyperLink in GridView.  You can use CommangArgument and CommandName Property to Hold the specic data. When u clicked the hyperlink the data will be passed as querystring to the next page. so that you can use the querytring

And to display " ... more" you can use substring method.. substring for a legnth and concat the ....more to your hyperlink text.

[MSDN for CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx)

[Sample for Passing data with LinkButton](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

Handle OnRowDataBound as so:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // say for example that the column with long text is the 5th one
      e.Row.Cells[5].Text =  e.Row.Cells[5].Text.Length>20?e.Row.Cells[5].Substring(0,20)+" <a href=\"DetailsPage.aspx?BlogID=\""+e.Row.Cells[0].Text+"\"> more...</a>";
    }

  }
```

Where the first column (`Cells[0]`) has the blog ID. I think that's how you have your gridview now.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're looking for the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` CSS styling. You can then use jQuery or plain javascript to toggle the style and reveal all the text.

I'm not quite sure how this is handled by Firefox today, but IE is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <%# (Eval("strDescription").ToString().Length > 55 ? Eval("strDescription").ToString().Substring(0, 55) + "....." : Eval("strDescription"))%>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

and just add hyperlink in this item template and assign your blogid(in your case) to that hyperlink to open detail page that you want.